# android proxy application

Tags: java, android, redirect, proxy

I want to create an android application that acts like a proxy, all Internet communication (at least http) will be redirected to this app before reaching the network.

I don't have any idea how to do it, so any help is welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible without rooting the phone, as this blog post aptly explains:

http://android-proxy.blogspot.com/

Edit: It's actually a dedicated blog site!

Comment: I found this on the internet:
http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/net/Proxy.java.shtml

Comment: I can set a proxy to localhost:someport but how can I implement an app that listen to that port and intercept the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think that the best solution is to implement a service that handles the http request and forward them using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient but I don't know how to do it.